# In MS Word, how do I prevent a bullet/number from modifying when changing the color/size of the rest of its line?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

In Microsoft Word 2013, is it possible to prevent a bullet/number from changing color/size when changing the color/size of rest of the line it's on?

For example, I have the following in an MS Word document:

> 1. Joe Shmoe
> 2. Marylou

And I subsequently highlight Joe Shmoe and make the color orange, the number will also be made orange. The same happens for Marylou.

I understand the blank character (pilcrow) at the end of each line has some kind of control over the bullet/number's formatting. But even if I carefully highlight the line not to include the hidden pilcrow, the bullet/number still changes formatting.

As a workaround I've been doing the formatting changes to the first few characters of the line and then the latter characters. Doing the line in 2 parts prevents the bullet/number from taking on the formatting change being done on the line. But I'd like to make it so this isn't a two-step process anymore. How can I accomplish this (without the side-effect of being unable to individually format numbers/bullets in general)?

Comment: This will be much easier to do if you make the paragraph marks visible.

Comment: Absolutely not. The same issue occurs with paragraph marks made visible. Either way, I want to be able to select the whole line (possibly even the pilcrow) and still not have the bullet/number change formatting.

Answer (score 4):

The color of the bullet in the default list type is set to "automatic" which leads to the behavior that you are struggling with.

You can change this by placing your cursor in the list in question, click the small arrow next to the following icon from the ribbon and choose "Define New List Type":

[image]

Set the bullet color from "automatic" to "black". Thats it. From now on the color of the bullet is not affected anymore, if you change the text color of the list item.

Comment: Thanks for your response Manuel. This certainly prevents the bullet from changing color when the line changes color. However, this has the additional side effect of preventing me from modifying the color of individual bullets. It forces all bullets to be the color I set for any one bullet.

Comment: Thats true @Raj, but you did not ask for a way to color bullets individually. Your question was, if it is "possible to prevent a bullet/number from changing color/size when changing the color/size of rest of the line it's on".

Comment: Yes, but I did not expect the solution to result in the loss of other basic formatting features.

Comment: @Raj, if I failed to answer your question, please update your question to state more clearly, what you want to achieve.

Comment: it's just as I said in the above comments. I've also updated the question for clarity, as you suggested.